# Uploading files to a site, just like API

Tags: php, curl, compilation, java

I have a hard or maybe easy question for you
Does anyone of you know how to do the following:

I found a site
http://www.innovation.ch/java/java_compile.html

And I would like to use it for my own site

So when I put a file in a directory, it automatically uploads it on that site
For example in the "Source file 1" and an other file in the "Jar file 1"

After that it has to press on the 1.7.0 option and after that it has to click on compile.

If that is done it has to download the allclasses.zip file when the compile command is executed

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm very curious?

Comment: This is more a list of requirements for a quote than a question imho.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  That page looks like a pretty standard HTML form, which I imagine constructs a pretty standard HTTP POST request.  You can create a POST request in code and send it to that site.  There are multiple ways to do this depending on the language/framework/etc. you're using.

Comment: I agree David, but if it needs a multipart upload it will be easier to use a script than to try to put the command together on the command line. See wget or curl if you want that route thou.

Comment: By the way, you are trusting that web site not in inject extra code (like a trojan) in the resulting executable.

Comment: Just like an api moving fast,light, and slim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can script interacting with the web pretty easily, consider for instance Mechanize for Perl or Ruby, http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize, http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/, or do it with Selenium: http://seleniumhq.org/.

Comment: Thanks for those replies guys, I really appreciatie it!
I'll give it a try and will let you know